# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON when making a GET request with mongoose geoNear

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to GET users based on their distance compared to the coordinates set in the parameters, however I get the above mentioned error, and I am pretty stuck on it for a while.

The JSON object

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a26be9a7397ab0a60857a1b"),
    "username" : "user",
    "email" : "user@gmail.com",
    "password" : "password",
    "geometry" : {
        "coordinates" : [ 
            55.452278, 
            12.313711
        ],
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a26be9a7397ab0a60857a1c"),
        "type" : "point"
    },
    "available" : false,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

The GET request, with geoNear command:

```
api.get(ghosts_path, (req, res, next) => {
Ghost.geoNear(
  {type: 'Point', coordinates: [parseFloat(req.query.lng),parseFloat(req.query.lat)]},
  {maxDistance: 1000000, spherical: true}
).then( (ghosts) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;');
  res.write(JSON.stringify(ghosts));
  res.end();
})
```

});

Comment: Is that JSON object for `ghosts` in `.then()`? Because this error usually pops during `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Hi. The json object is one of the objects i have added with postman, through POST requests. It seems that it doesn't even get until 'then'.